# Vertex AI Endpoints - Failed to create endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to deploy a custom model to an endpoint with Vertex AI. I run the custom training and the model was correctly created in my bucket using Tensorflow 2 `export_saved_model` for estimators. In this bucket there is the `saved_model.pb` file with the folder `variables`.
However, when I try to create an endpoint selecting the path to the saved model, the following error occurs:

`Failed to create endpoint "endpoint_name" due to error: APPLICATION_ERROR; google.cloud.ml.v1/ModelService.CreateVersion;Field: version.deployment_uri Error: Deployment directory gs://different_bucket/artifacts/ is expected to contain exactly one of: [saved_model.pb, saved_model.pbtxt].`

It seems it is searching the .pb file in a bucket that is not the one I set.
Suggestions?

Comment: Have you followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/deploy-model-api#aiplatform_create_endpoint_sample-gcloud) to create an endpoint?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I tried to create it from console and from workbench with python, but I got the same error.

Comment: Based on the error, it seems like your storage bucket has multiple model files inside of it. Can you update the bucket to include only one model file and try?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I solved the problem setting the previous folder in the path; so, instead of ```gs://my_bucket/my_folder/model ``` I chose ```gs://my_bucket/my_folder```

Comment: If you have resolved the issue, can you add the resolution steps as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem changing the folder to pass during the endpoint creation. I have the model in the following path:

`gs://my_bucket/my_folder/model/saved_model.pb`

Instead of pointing to `gs://my_bucket/my_folder/model/` I used `gs://my_bucket/my_folder` and it worked.